# len of nparray inside pandas cell

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a single Pandas column and each cell inside has a various number of elements of a Numpy array.
when trying to obtain the number of elements of the array inside each row, I only get the total number of rows of the column when trying the following:

```
df['elements'] = np.size(df['column'])
df['elements'] = len(df['column'])
df['elements'] = df['column'].size
```

I've also been thrown errors or syntax issues when trying:

```
df['elements'] = df['column'].apply(len)
```

What is the proper way of getting the number of elements inside each cell with a Numpy Array?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df['elements'] = df['column'].str.len()
```